# Wordpress: Pass $wpdb->insert_id from 1 function to another?

Tags: hook, wordpress

I'm trying to do something simple. I think my code looks sound, but for some reason, the `$wpdb->insert_id;` keeps being empty? Am I doing something wrong here? Am I doing the passing of the variable correctly? I even tried storing `$wpdb->insert_id;` in a `$_SESSION` but it was still empty.

```
function insert_stuff() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('mytable',
        array(
        'column1' => $_REQUEST['formitem1'],
        'column2' => $_REQUEST['formitem2'],
        )
    );
    global $lastid;
    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id; 
}
add_action('add_to_cart', 'insert_stuff');

function update_stuff() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $lastid;

    $wpdb->update('mytable', array('column3' => 'newvalue'), array('id' => $lastid), array('%s'), array('%d'));
}
add_action('thank_you_page', 'update_stuff');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an array with the $wpdb->insert..

```
$wpdb->insert(
'table',
  array(
    'column1' => $var1,
    'column2' => $var2,
  ),
  array(
    '%d',
    '%s',
  )
);
```

*Note: %d = numbers.. %s =  string..*

Best of luck.